# Grails - Upgrade and downgrade version of the project

Tags: grails

I made an example project in grails 2.3.8. How to upgrade to the newest version? No way to downgrade from version too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the differences between the versions.  In a lot of cases you will get away with simply editing the version number in the `application.properties` file at the top of the project.  There used to be a `grails upgrade` command which attempted to do some of the work for you but that approach proved to be problematic for a number of reasons so it was removed in Grails 2.4.  The normal upgrade procedure now is to edit the version number, which can be done using the `grails set-version` command (which just updates `application.properties`, see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-grails-version.html) and then reading release notes for any other particulars related to that release.  Often the release notes suggest updating some specific plugins to specific version numbers for compatibility.

Downgrading generally could be done with the same approach.  Depending on what is in your application you might run into problems going backwards in versions.

I hope that helps.